# Rails 4.0 + Passenger Standalone: Setting the database pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, connection-pooling

I want to change the number of database pool per process from 5 to 10.

I'm using Passenger Standalone as my application web server. Unfortunately, as I'm using Rails 4 (not 4.1+), I'm not able to specify the `pool` value on my `database.yml`, so I must come up with another solution.

This https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#multi-process-servers suggests a fix for multi-process app servers (such as Passenger) but the code only works for Unicorn.

I have not been able to find a way to change the database pool size when Passenger is the app server.

How can I do it?

Thanks!